# JS / Как показать блок, только когда картинка из CSS загрузилась?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, изображения

Задача следующая - Есть некий блок обертка, внутри которого находиться div(с анимацией) большого размера. Вопрос - Как отследить что картинка которая задается через backgroud-image уже полностью загрузилась. И уже после этого показать этот блок?

Попробую сделать простой пример:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.wrapper.active {
  display: block;
}

.myAnimation {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url("https://www.placecage.com/gif/200/300") 50% 50% no-repeat;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="myAnimation"></div>
  <p>Если ты это читаешь, значит большая картинка загрузилась</p>
</div>
```

Как узнать что картинка готова к показу, и можно, для блока .wrapper добавить класс .active . Но не раньше ?
ПС В интернете есть довольно много примеров, как данная задача решается, если картинка б задавалась в теге img. (событие .onload) Но вот как быть если она CSS background-image ? (Реальная картинка порядка 20-30mB)

Comment: похоже, решения при картинке в css нет

Comment: наверно можно затолкать в нужный блок тяжёлую картинку и должаться DomContentLoaded а потом картику удалить ...может быть это вариант

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached)

Comment: с css вряд ли можно

Comment: Я правильно понял, что в предложном примере, ребята создают дубль изображения в теге img, а уже когда он загрузиться, этот img отслеживают и скрывают потом по ненадобности ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/qBdVxaw если вариант конечно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно создать картинку через конструктор `new Image()`, скопировать туда адрес картинки и поймать его `onload`. Это не одно и то же, что поймать загрузку именно background-image, но гарантирует, что последний точно будет загружен перед выполнением функции.

```js
awaitBgImgLoad();

function awaitBgImgLoad() {
  var div = document.querySelector('.myAnimation');
  var src = window.getComputedStyle(div).backgroundImage;
  console.log(src); // адрес хранится в виде `url("src")` — надо удалить лишние символы
  
  src = src.replace(/url\(|\)|"/g,"")
  loadAndRun(src, onload);
  
  /***/
  
  function onload() {
    console.log("Я загрузился!");
    document.querySelector('.wrapper').style.display = "block";
  }
}

/*****/

function loadAndRun(src, resolve, reject) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = resolve;
  img.onerror = reject || function(){
    console.log("Не загрузилась " + src)
  };
  img.src = src;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.wrapper.active {
  display: block;
}

.myAnimation {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 247px;
  height: 187px;
  background: url("https://gyazo.com/f5d013014306342a2241f8d3b8fb11ea.png") 50% 50% no-repeat;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="myAnimation"></div>
  <p>Я загрузился!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Хороший вариант, а как вы считаете, если не создавать данную картинку средствами JS.А добавить в DOM дерево img с таким же адресом, с свойствами position:absolute; left:100000px; к примеру, а уже отслеживать на нём загрузилась или нет. Будет ли такой вариант правильнее? *Я просто где-то читал что html img имеет больший приоритет по загрузке, чем background-image. По сути же браузер грузит один раз картинку, а все остальные копии берет из кэша, или нет ?

Comment: Упс, точно не скажу все плюсы и минусы. Но такой вариант тоже будет работать. Просто показалось удобнее сделать это прямо из скрипта и не возиться с HTML)

Comment: @BlackStar1991 только не absolute а fixed

Comment: @MaximLensky а в чём разниться, как именно скрыть псевдоизображение от наблюдателя ?

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME Я чего подумал за этот метод - сейчас же можно прикрутить к тегу img атрибут loading="lazy" или loading="eager" и как-бы подсказать, браузеру... хотя конечно тут всё упираться в этот офигенно большой размер изображения

Comment: @BlackStar1991 вверху в комментарии есть пример